# Is there possible combobox that mobile detail cost for display total cost in label as in vb?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i doing assignment programming and design Principles,
i done write code for that radbutton and checkbox and total cost display in a label but should i put combo box for the manufacturer: Apple,Samsung or Sony? because i think impossible put mobile details cost in label

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    ComboManfacturer.Items.Add("Apple")
    ComboManfacturer.Items.Add("Samsung")
    ComboManfacturer.Items.Add("Sony")

    ComboManfacturer.SelectedItem = 0

    End Sub 



     Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
     BtnCalc.Click

    'Declaring
    Const CostApple As Double = 1000
    Const CostSamsung As Double = 500
    Const CostSony As Double = 300


   'put mobile as total cost display in a label 
   Combobox.SelectIndex("Apple" & CostApple)
   Combobox.SelectIndex("Samsung" & CostSamsung)
   Combobox.SeleectIndex("Sony" & CostSony)


    'process - where you figure out answers which total cost in the label
    Total = quantity * Total


    'output
    LblTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(Total)
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use classes? A simple class with two properties (Manufacturer, `string` and Cost, `decimal`), can be used as the source of a ComboBox Items collection. The `DisplayMember` can be the `Manufacturer` property, the `ValueMember` can be the Cost property. The ComboBox will show the `Manufacturer` string, on selection change, you can get the Value of the `SelectedItem`, represented by the `Cost` property.

Comment: My assignment says, the form should contain the following, a combo box for manufacturer: Apple, Samsung or Sony.                    when button is clicked, the mobile details and the total cost will be displayed in a label but i tried it and still wont work for me

Comment: What do you mean with *the total cost*? Are you allowing a user to select more that one item from the ComboBox, thus you need a *total*? Or you just allow a single selection, showing the related (single) cost? If the latter, Mary's code already shows that.

Comment: radbuttons and check boxes already total in label but combo boxes, it wont show in label, im really apologise that im not too good english . i hope i trying make you understand but i think i send you email that i screenshot of my vb design and then you have to reply so future viewers able can see , you get it ? :)

Comment: If you want to clarify your question, you can update it clicking on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53999477/edit) link. You can also post an image, if you think it will help to explain your requirements. Don't worry if SO won't allow you to show it, someone will take care of that.

Comment: but it wont let me upload image but i can send you email gmail or hotmail so you will  be like " Okay i understand, its easy" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be what events you are using for your code. Fill the combo in the Form load event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("Apple")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("Samsung")
    ComboBox2.Items.Add("Sony")
End Sub
```

Then in the ComboBox's SelectionChangeCommitted event provide the appropriate values.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim s As String = ""
    Select Case ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "Apple"
            s = "1000"
        Case "Samsung"
            s = "500"
        Case "Sony"
            s = "300"
    End Select
    Label1.Text = s
End Sub
```

It would be better to use a class as suggested by @Jimi but I provide this solution if you have not been introduced to classes yet.

The Select Case can be replaced with a series of If statements if the Case statement has yet to be introduced in your course.

```
    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString = "Apple" Then
        s = "1000"
    End If
```

**EDIT**

```
Private Function GetSelectedRadioButton(ctrl As ContainerControl) As RadioButton
    Dim rButton As RadioButton = ctrl.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton).FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Checked = True)
    Return rButton
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Use Decimal datatype for money
    Dim Total As Decimal
    'Get cost form radio button
    Dim rb As RadioButton = GetSelectedRadioButton(Me)
    'Put the cost for the each radio button in the .Tag property of the button
    Total += CDec(rb.Tag)
    'Get cost from check boxes
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox AndAlso DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).Checked Then
            'Store the cost in the .Tag property of the checkbox
            Total += CDec(ctrl.Tag)
        End If
    Next
    'Get cost from combobox
    Dim d As Decimal
    Select Case ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "Apple"
            d = 1000
        Case "Samsung"
            d = 500
        Case "Sony"
            d = 300
    End Select
    Total += d
    Dim Quantity as Decimal = CDec(txtQuantity.Text)
    Total = Quantity * Total
    Label1.Text = Total.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me, i mean i need mobile details cost which display in label after radbuttons and checkbutton that has result cost in one label as i click button of calculator

Comment: See EDIT to my code. Just more the Select Case to the Button Click event.

Comment: still not work, i think you are bit confused, i mean thats not what i mean, like i said i need combo box to cost display in a label. oh maybe i can screenshot of my form vb  design that i created and you will understand? email you?

Comment: The first code I posted satisfies "i need combo box to cost display in a label." If we start email communication it does not help future viewers.

Comment: Okay but My assignment says, the form should contain the following, a combo box for manufacturer: Apple, Samsung or Sony.                                               radbutton for storage, 32gb or 64gb                                                                               check boxes for extras, 12 megaxiplex and battery life                                                 texbox for quantity between 1 and 100                                                                     when button is clicked, the mobile details and the total cost will be displayed in a label

Comment: Added a line to my EDIT for the quantity textbox.

Comment: Oh i did added a line but doent work at all :( but i can email you that screenshot of my vb design to you see them and understand so you can explain here, not on email

Comment: Post your code as an edit to your question and explain exactly what doesn't work. Do you get an error message? What displays in the label? There are third party sites where you can post images and provide a link. Soon you will be able to add images to your question when you have enough reps.

Comment: but it wont let me upload image but i can send you email gmail or hotmail so you will  be like " Okay i understand, its easy" :)

Comment: It is the code I need to look at. I don't see any edit to your question. Post your updated code as an edit.

Comment: but i think i would send you email, you would quick solve problem 100%

Comment: Sorry, that is not the way it is done on Stack Overflow. Have you even tried my code?

Comment: No i mean i want you see image of vb design that i told you about my code and then you can do explain on stack overflow, and yes i did tried but not work, its okay if you dont want me send you email but you want me type clear code i wrote

Comment: Yes, can you copy and paste your code? Otherwise, type it in but be sure to format as code. Highlight and use Ctrl+K or use {} on toolbar.

Comment: It doesn't appear that paid any attention to my suggestions. So, I guess you are on your own. Sorry I could not help.  :-)

Comment: what you do mean? i thought i sent you my code...  so you could help :( but its okay i will keep trying myself and thank for your time, i really appreciate it :)